# Why does getting error in compiling Specify7, specifically on the webpack "frontend"?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ubuntu, webpack

I got the issue of compiling the front-end webpack. I follow the guide on https://github.com/specify/specify7 but had no luck. see the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkgsj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I did an update of the latest version of nodejs and npm, and these updates resolve my compiling issues.

I follow the instruction on this link : [nodejs update](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version)